# libgdx - moving an object

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So, I'm farely new to programming this is my first game, and I have been working on it for a while, for one of my classes and I'm creating a pong game just changed it up a bit and I'm having trouble moving my paddle from the left to the center everytime I change the the percentage of the width of the screen to move it for some reason it elevates the paddle by all almost the same. Also everything is controlled by the width for some bizarre reason its almost like the field.height has no effect on moving it? I'm stuck right here and I'm so close to finishing it I'm trying to lower the paddle to the bottom center? any help would really be appreciated and hopefully this makes sense.

here is the field

```
@Override
public void create () { 
    field.set(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    fieldLeft = field.x;
    fieldRight = field.x + field.width;
    fieldBottom = field.y;
    fieldTop = field.y + field.height;
```

and here is the paddle movement

```
private void resetRectangle(){
    paddle1.move(field.x + (field.width * .5f, 0);
    paddle2.move(0,0);
}
```

and the class

```
public class Paddle extends GameShare{

private ShapeRenderer paddleRenderer;


protected Paddle() {
    super(100, 32);
}

public void paddleCreate(){
    paddleRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

}

public void paddleRender(float dt){
    paddleRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    drawPaddle(dt);
    paddleRenderer.end();
}

private void drawPaddle(float dt) {
    paddleRenderer.rect(this.getX(), this.getX(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    paddleRenderer.rect(this.getX(), this.getX(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

}
```

Comment: You should use `camera` or `viewport`, cause this helps you by supporting differen resolutions and aspect ratios. It alowes you to use your own coordinates, which the `camera` tehn converts to pixels. So basicly you can say, you want to have 80 units in `y`-Axis. Now, if you move 1 unit, on a 1920*1080 resolution, the `camera` would move 24px (1920/80), while on a 800*600 resolution it would move only 10px. So the relative movement is always the same.

Comment: Your `drawPaddle`method is using `this.getX()` for the y argument instead of `this.getY()`. Also, you're drawing it twice in the exact same spot, which is redundant.